# Reading a directory in shell script

Tags: shell-script, filenames, wildcards, sort

I want to read a numbered directory which is under a path, into a variable in shell script.
The paths are something like this:

```
.../releases/R1/...
.../releases/R2/...
.../releases/R3/...
```

Each time that the script is executed I want to read the latest numbered R (R3 in this case) directory into a variable and then pass this as an argument to some functions inside the script.
How shall I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest if you're using zsh, thanks to its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `[-1]` to retain the last match and `n` to use numeric sorting so that `R9` comes before `R10`. You can also take advantage of its `<->` glob pattern to match numbers.

```
last_release=(releases/R<->(n[-1]))
if (($#last_release == 0)); then
  echo 1>&2 "Fatal error: no release available"
  exit 2
fi
```

With only portable tools, the easiest method is to offload the numeric sorting to `sort`. If you only have “tame” file names in the `releases` directory (ASCII characters only, no control characters, no whitespace), filtering the output of `ls` is a handy way of generating the list of file names.

```
set_last_release () {
  set -- $(ls releases | sed -n 's/^R\([0-9][0-9]*\)//p' | sort -rn)
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "Fatal error: no release available"
    exit 2
  fi
  last_release=releases/R$1
}
```

If you use leading zeroes in your release numbers, you can rely on the shell's built-in sorting. Note that there is no portable way to match only file names consisting of `R` followed by one or more digit; in ksh, you can use `releases/R+([0-9])`, and you can also use this in bash if you put `shopt -s extglob` at the beginning of your script (it must be in effect both when the function is parsed and when it is executed).

```
set_last_release () {
  set -- releases/R[0-9]*
  if [ "$1" = 'releases/R[0-9]*' ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "Fatal error: no release available"
    exit 2
  fi
  eval last_release=\$$#
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about that:

```
DIRECTORY=$(ls .../releases | tail -n 1)
```

This works as long as your directory names can be sorted like strings. for example a '2' would be after a '12', unless you name the '2' actually '02'

Comment: Otherwise, If your directories can't be sorted as strings and you can't change their names, you may also do this ` for i in {1..1000}; do if [ ! -d .../releases/R${i} ]; then break; fi; done; let i=${i}-1` in the end ${i} is the number of the latest directory

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this :

```
for dir in releases/R*[0-9]/; do
   echo "$dir"
done
```